# Compile AS3 swf using Flash CS5

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

Here got a bunch of actionscript, any idea how can I compile it using Flash CS5 (unfortunately I don't have flashbuilder)

https://github.com/jwagener/recorder.js/tree/master/flash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which programming environment you are using, but [FDT](http://fdt.powerflasher.com) provides a lot of features that are beyond the simple compilation and deploy of your ActionScript apps.

Alternatively, you can use the [flex framework](http://incubator.apache.org/flex/) (Which is now under apache) tools to compile your apps